# Preview large video while still downloading it in Skype

Tags: skype, video-streaming, file-download

Is there a way to start watching partially downloaded video from Skype while it is still being downloaded? So far my experience was that as soon as I try to do that - Skype interrupts the download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this cannot be accomplished.